# Minimum quadratic form value within a line?

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-forms

If I have $x\in R^n , C\in R^{m\times n}, d\in R^m$, $m<n$, then $Cx=d$ is a linear manifold.

And $P\in R^{n\times n}$, $P>0$, the quadratic form is $y=x^TPx$

Is there an analytical expression of the minimum value of $y$ for $Cx=d$ ?

For $n=3, m=2$, it's like the minimum distance from  points on a line to the original point.

I want to use this as a constraint in convex optimization.

Comment: Have you ever heard of lagrange multiplier?

Comment: No. Is it useful for this problem? Thanks, I'll see if it can help.

Comment: Read this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)

Answer (score 2):

Apply [lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) method. The augmented function looks like:
$$
f(x)=x^TPx+\lambda^T(Cx-d)
$$
Note that here $\lambda\in\mathbb R^m$ is a vector since you have $m$ constraints. The minimum is acquired when:
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial f/\partial x=2Px+C^T\lambda=0\\
\partial f/\partial\lambda=Cx-d=0
\end{cases}
$$
Since $P>0$ and therefore invertible, we have:
$$
x=-\frac{1}{2}P^{-1}C^T\lambda\Rightarrow Cx=-\frac{1}{2}(CP^{-1}C^T)\lambda=d
$$
Assume $C$ has full row rank, then:
$$
\lambda^*=-2(CP^{-1}C^T)^{-1}d
$$
Now the argument minimum $x^*$ is given by:
$$
x^*=-\frac{1}{2}P^{-1}C^T\lambda^*=P^{-1}C^T(CP^{-1}C^T)^{-1}d
$$
and the minimum value is given by:
$$
y^*=x^{*T}Px^*
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. By the way, how did you post  the formulas? Use MathJaX directly or by an easier software?

Comment: @g5999823 how did you do it? not latex??

Comment: I followed the tutorial http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to write it and I feel it's troublesome.

Comment: @g5999823 If you use some external editor to typeset the equations such as VIM, it would be much more efficient. By the way, it is not MathJax, it is LaTeX. We have a tex.stackexchange.com if you have noticed. If you think my answer is ok, please approve/upvote it. Otherwise you can wait for a better one.

Comment: @g5999823: It'd be better to upvote Troy Woo's answer before worrying about Mathjax, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I propose solving your problem iteratively using the primal-dual algorithm of [Chambolle & Pock](http://www.cmapx.polytechnique.fr/preprint/repository/685.pdf) (more precisely, Algorithms 1 & 2 of the paper).  This is also an opportunity to familiarize the reader with primal-dual & proximal algorithms, a contemporary technology which is apparently not yet quite popular.

**Relaxed asumptions.** You only need to assume the weaker condition $P \succeq 0$. If $P \succ 0$, then a quadratic acceleration over the basic algorithm is guaranteed. Most importantly, you don't need any assumptions on $C$ whatsoever.

To begin with, first observe that your problem can be conveniently written in the form
\begin{eqnarray}
\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\text{minimize }}g(x) + f(Cx),
\end{eqnarray}
where $g: x \mapsto \langle x, Px\rangle$ and $f = i_{\{d\}}: u \mapsto \begin{cases}0, &\mbox{ if }u = d,\\+\infty, &\mbox{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$

If your are a physicist, think of $f$ as an infinite potential well concentrated at $d$. Note that both $g$ and $f$ are *proper* convex functions. The above problem is the primal form of the following saddle-point (equilibrium) problem
\begin{eqnarray}
\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\text{minimize }}\underset{u \in \mathbb{R}^m}{\text{maximize }}\langle Cx, u\rangle + g(x) - f^*(u),
\end{eqnarray}
where $h^*:u \mapsto \underset{z \in \mathbb{R}^m}{\text{sup }}\langle z, u\rangle - h(z)$ is the *Fenchel-Legendre transform* (aka *convex conjugate*) of a proper convex lower semi-continuous function $h \in \Gamma_0(\mathbb{R}^m)$. In your case, an easy computation reveals $f^*(u) \equiv \langle d, u\rangle$.

You'll need the following ingredients to implement the algorithms of the reference paper.

**Proximal operator of $f^*$.** Given a scalar $\sigma > 0$, and a point $u \in \mathbb{R}^m$, one computes
\begin{eqnarray}
prox_{\sigma f^*}(u) := \underset{z \in \mathbb{R}^m}{\text{argmin }}\frac{1}{2}\|z-u\|^2 + \sigma f^*(z) = 
\underset{z \in \mathbb{R}^m}{\text{argmin }}\frac{1}{2}\|z-u\|^2 + \sigma \langle d, z\rangle = u - \sigma d.
\end{eqnarray}

**Proximal operator of $g$.** Given a scalar $\tau > 0$, one computes
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{split}
prox_{\tau g}(x) &:= \underset{z \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\text{argmin }}\frac{1}{2}\|z-x\|^2 + \tau g(z) = 
\underset{z \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\text{argmin }}\frac{1}{2}\|z-x\|^2 + \tau \langle x, Px\rangle\\
 &= (I + \tau P^TP)^{-1}x.
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}

Remarkably, the above computation can be carried out using the cached SVD (singular-value decomposition of $P$), thus avoiding the matrix inversion.
Indeed, let $P = USV^*$ be the SVD of $P$, where $U$ and $V$ are $n$-by-$n$ unitary matrices and $S$ is an $n$-by-$n$ diagonal matrix with nonnegative decreasing diagonal entries $s_1 \ge s_2 \ge ... \ge s_r > 0 = s_{r+1} = ... = s_n$. Then,
\begin{eqnarray}
(I + \tau P^*P)^{-1}x = (I + \tau V^*S^*U^*USV^*)^{-1}x = (I + \tau V^*S^*SV^*)^{-1}x = V^*DVx,
\end{eqnarray}

where $D := diag\left(\frac{1}{1 + \tau s_1^2}, \frac{1}{1 + \tau s_2^2}, ..., \frac{1}{1 + \tau s_r^2}, 1, 1, ..., 1\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

BTW, note that $r = rank(P)$.

**Square of Lipschitz constant $L$.** We have
\begin{eqnarray}
L^2 := \|C\|^2 = \lambda_{max}(C^*C) = \lambda_{max}(CC^*),
\end{eqnarray}
which can be computed via the [power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration).

**Modulus of strong-convexity of $g$.** Notice that if $P \succ 0$, then $g$ is strongly-convex, with modulus of convexity $\gamma = \lambda_{min}(P^*P) = \lambda_{min}(P^2)  = \lambda_{min}(P)^2$ = square of the smallest eigenvalue of $P = s_n^2 > 0$.

**The algorithm and its rate of convergence.**
Now apply Algorithm 2 if $P \succ 0$ and Algorithm 1 otherwise, of the reference paper with these settings.
According to Theorem 2, the resultant algorithm should converge in $\mathcal{O}(1/\sqrt{\zeta})$ iterations in the former case and $\mathcal{O}(1/\zeta)$ in the latter case, where $\zeta$ is a tolerance on the primal-dual gap.

**Further reading.**
For the kinds of problems you seem interested in (signal recovery, compressed sensing, etc.), you may want to read the following [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.0436v4.pdf) by P.L. Combettes.

I hope this was all useful. Let me know if you need more (implementation) details.

Cheers!